# starting container process caused "exec: > \"exec\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: linux, docker, docker-run

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM 939fj39f3932.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/teros_keys:8e31674

WORKDIR /zoom

COPY app.sh .

ENTRYPOINT ["exec", "/zoom/app.sh"]
CMD []
```

I build it and it works fine. Then I run it with:

```
docker run --rm -d \
    -e "db_prefix=$db_prefix" \
    --name "$n" "$full_name"
```

and I get this error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"exec\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

anyone know what's up with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed it to:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/zoom/app.sh"]
```

and it worked, dunno why tho

Comment: As stated in David's answer, `exec` is a built-in of the shell, not a standalone command. Also, a best practice to follow would be invoking `/bin/bash`, using the absolute path, that one does not need to rely on the `PATH` defined in the container.

Answer (score 6):

When you use the JSON-array form of `ENTRYPOINT` (or `CMD` or `RUN`), the command is run exactly as-is.  There is no shell handling at all.  [`exec`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_20), though, is what the standard refers to as a "special built-in utility"; it only exists within the context of a shell.  Docker winds up looking for a `/bin/exec` or `/usr/bin/exec` tool, and it's not there, yielding that error message.

If you can just run the script as is (it's executable and has a correct "shebang" line `#!/bin/sh` or similar) then you don't need a modifier like `exec`.  You can just specify it directly

```sh
# No ENTRYPOINT
CMD ["/zoom/app.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue is I tried to use like this `CMD ["ls -a"]`.

resolution:
changed to `CMD ["ls", "-a"]`